# Unable to get standard error for values A,cB,and C determined from function

Tags: python, numpy

For the code below, I can't get a standard error for the individual values of A, B, and C.  I've tried a few different ways, and either come up with 0 or with a singular value. The method below is the latest way I tried but which didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am new to Python.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import pylab
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import sympy as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
x = np.array([600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950,1000])
y = np.array([.124,.627,2.492,8.187,23.06,57.24,127.9,261.6,496.5])
lny = np.log(y)
plt.plot(x,lny,'.')
plt.show()
def func(x,a,b,c):
    return a+b/x+c*np.log(x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,lny)
print popt
a,b,c = (popt)
print a
print b
print c
stdvfunc = np.std(func(x,a,b,c))
print stdvfunc
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Remove all the \` marks, select the code, and click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard deviations of a, b, and c are

```
pcov[0,0]**0.5
pcov[1,1]**0.5 #and 
pcov[2,2]**0.5
```

respectively.

The documentation is referenced and copied below.  See the bold italicized text.

---

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

pcov : 2d array

The estimated covariance of popt. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate. ***To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use***

```
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)).
```

How the sigma parameter affects the estimated covariance depends on absolute_sigma argument, as described above.

If the Jacobian matrix at the solution doesn’t have a full rank, then ‘lm’ method returns a matrix filled with np.inf, on the other hand ‘trf’ and ‘dogbox’ methods use Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse to compute the covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm reading the link you supplied and that plus your explanation makes it really clear why nothing I've been trying worked.  I appreciate your help.